# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{-bx}}{\sqrt{x^2 +a^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is the following integral solvable analytically? $a$ and $b$ are constants.
$$
\int_0^\infty  \frac{xe^{-bx}}{\sqrt{x^2 +a^2}}dx 
$$

Comment: Yes it is, just see what is the derivative of $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$

Comment: If you mean by change of variable, I dont think it would help much since we would get $e^{(-u^{0.5})}$

Comment: I didn't meant by change of variable.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Oh I actually missread. Indeed, I don't think you can solve this one analytically...

Comment: Is it $a^2/4$ (as in the title) or $a^2$ (as in the post) ?

Comment: I think this is Laplace's Transform of the function.

Answer (score 5):

Letting $x=a\sinh t$ or $x=\dfrac a2~\sinh t$, and employing the integral expressions for the [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function), we ultimately arrive at $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac u{\sqrt{u^2+1}}~e^{-cu}~du~=~\int_0^\infty\sinh t\cdot e^{-c\sinh t}~dt~=$ $=-\dfrac\pi2\Big[Y_1(c)+H_{-1}(c)\Big]$, where *c* is a parameter whose expression depends on *a* and *b*.

Comment: Could you determine what is c?

Comment: @Hesam we have $c=ab$.

Comment: @Hesam: Of course I can, but, then again, so can you. Just let $x=au$ or $x=\dfrac a2~u$, and then compare the two expressions.

Answer (score 2):

This will be a very modest contribution after Lucian's answer.

Starting with  $$I=\int_0^\infty  \frac{xe^{-bx}}{\sqrt{x^2 +a^2}}dx$$ and changing variable $x=a y$, we have $$I=a\int_0^\infty \frac{y\, e^{-c y}}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}dy$$ with $c=ab$. We can perform a Taylor expansion and get $$\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}=y-\frac{y^3}{2}+\frac{3 y^5}{8}-\frac{5 y^7}{16}+\frac{35 y^9}{128}-\frac{63
   y^{11}}{256}+O\left(y^{13}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_iy^i$$ and we are just left with integrals $$J_n=\int_0^\infty  y^n e^{-cy}dy=\frac{n!}{c^{n+1}}$$

**Edit** : Robjohn's comment "*This will only give an asymptotic series in $c$ since the radius of convergence is $0$*" must be very seriously taken into account.

Comment: This will only give an asymptotic series in $c$ since the radius of convergence is $0$.

Comment: @robjohn. I hope you will not be surprized if I say that I totally agree with you.

Comment: It would be good to mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

(answer requires analysis of one complex variable)

Let us first replace the numerator with $|x|e^{-b|x|}$ as this would not make any difference for our problem. Now create a half circle, positive imaginary half plane, centered at origo and let radius grow without bounds. Obviously at the arc, our function value would diminish much faster than the radius grows. Then let us observe that our function is even with respect to the real part of x. So the value of our contour integral is $2I$ where $I$ is the integral we seek. Furthermore we see that there are two poles of our function, located at $x = \pm ai$. However only the positive one is inside our contour.

Now we can use the residue theorem to calculate 2I. That can be left as an exercise :)

Comment: $|z|e^{-b|z|}$ is not analytic. The residue theorem does not apply.

Comment: Really? If we define $|x_0| = (a_0^2+b_0^2)^{1/2}$ where $x_0 = a_0+b_0i$ (added the indexes to avoid confusion with the b in the exponent)

Comment: Even $|z|$ is not an analytic function. Apply the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) to check it out.

Comment: Oh, how sad. The negative half plane gets troublesome if b in the exponent is positive. Then one would have to go along the imaginary line but that's exactly where the residue is.